# Copying invoice between .gnucash files

Tags: gnucash, transfer

Is there a way to easily copy a single Invoice from one .gnucash file, to another .gnucash file?

Comment: Do both `.gnucash` files share the same origin? That means did you start off with one `.gnucash` file and then duplicated _the file_ before the contents diverged? The point is, do both ledgers share the same IDs with respect to the involved accounts and vendors?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to this question is **NO**.

There probably is a way to extract the information for a single invoice - *but it's not easy*.

By default, GnuCash maintains your data in XML format, and stores it as a compressed file with a .gnucash suffix. You can get your data into editable form by just uncompressing it first.  Then use your favourite text editor to find and copy the relevant XML tags and associated data to extract the invoice information from the "donor" .gnucash file.

Repeat the process with the "recipient" .gnucash file, pasting the invoice information  in text form into the file.  Close and save both files.

Sounds easy, right?  It's not.  ***It's probably going to be a finnicky, error-prone process with many opportunities to corrupt your GnuCash database.***

It would be easier, and far safer, to simply create the invoice in GnuCash using the standard tools for creating a New Invoice - or, even better, make a copy of an existing invoice for the same customer and modify as necessary.